What is the origin and meaning of 'rise and shine'?
What is the origin and meaning of 'rise and shine'? If the sun rises, it must shine. When is it used?

The exhortation to rise from bed, and then to 'shine', is not directed at the sun.

See this explanation.

Are you talking about the sun, or other things? Where did you see the phrase? (Note also that plenty of things rise but don't shine, while others - like the moon - shine variable amounts when risen, and there's no harm in stating something explicitly.)

@KateBunting I dunno, I'm highly skeptical of a through-line between the Isaiah instance and the "wakey wakey" instance. I'm not sure that's some top-shelf pro linguistic detectiving there, so much as "Hey look I found the string you were looking for, form your own conclusions about how it got there!"

It is said (usually) by parents to their children to tell them to get out of bed.
It is unlikely that many English learners would need to use it.  Probably it is a metaphor, telling the child to be like the sun, to get out of bed and be happy and "shiny". It may well derive from the bible, Isisah 60:1, but has no religious connotations now.

Come on Mr. Sleepy-head, up you get. Rise and shine! It's eight-thirty, morning has broken, the birds are singing and you have school in half-an-hour!
Awww mum! I was having a dream.

